# git push local file structure to the remote repo

Tags: git

I realized that the file structures (i.e., path of each file in the repo) in github repo is different from the local repo, after I moving .git to the parent directory. for example. my previous repo is in src/ and looks like:

```
repo/src/.git
repo/src/repofiles.c
```

after issusing the following commands

```
repo/src$ls -a
    repofiles.c .git
repo/src$mv .git ..
repo/src$cd ..
repo$mkdir example
repo$touch example/example1.c  && git add example/example1.c
repo$ls -a
   src example .git
repo$git commit -a && git push www.github
```

now in the remote repo, I have root folder with

```
repo/src/repofiles.c
repo/src/.git 
repo/src/example/example1.c
```

However i wish to have the following structures as my local structure has:

```
repo/src/repofiles.c
repo/examples/example.c
repo/.git/
```

the non-consistence file structure make the program not running for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you move a `.git`.

You don't move `.git`, you move everything else to match your target structure.

```
repo/src$ls -a
    repofiles.c .git

mkdir src                # I know: src/src but bear with me here
git mv repofiles.c src
mkdir example
touch example/example1.c  && git add example/example1.c
git commit -A && git push www.github
```

Then, check that the github repo reflect the new structure.

Locally, move your repo folder into an old one, and clone again

```
mv repo repo.old
git clone github/yourrepo repo
```

That way, you end up with:

```
repo/src/repofiles.c
repo/examples/example.c
repo/.git/
```